# What is a Hopeful Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Hopeful Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Hopeful Words™ | Not Hopeful Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| AGAINST | FOR |
| AGENTS | SPY |
| BASE | LOFTY |
| BATTLE | ACCORD |
| CIVIL | CHURLISH |
| DEATH | LIFE |
| DESTROY | REBUILD |
| EVIL | GOOD |
| POWER | RESPONSIBILITY |
| REBEL | COMPLY |
| SINISTER | HOPEFUL |
| STRIKING | CARESSING |
| VICTORY | DEFEAT |
| WAR | PEACE |
| WEAPON | PLOWSHARE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Hopeful Words™,Not Hopeful Words™
AGAINST,FOR
AGENTS,SPY
BASE,LOFTY
BATTLE,ACCORD
CIVIL,CHURLISH
DEATH,LIFE
DESTROY,REBUILD
EVIL,GOOD
POWER,RESPONSIBILITY
REBEL,COMPLY
SINISTER,HOPEFUL
STRIKING,CARESSING
VICTORY,DEFEAT
WAR,PEACE
WEAPON,PLOWSHARE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Hopeful Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Hopeful Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Well, this puzzle is easy to get once you get to one word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are...

> **Words that appear in *Star Wars: A New Hope*'s opening crawl:**
>
>  *Episode IV, A NEW HOPE: It is a period of **civil** **war**. **Rebel** spaceships, **striking** from a hidden **base**, have won their first **victory** **against** the **evil** Galactic Empire. During the **battle**, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire’s ultimate **weapon**, the **DEATH** STAR, an armored space station with enough **power** to **destroy** an entire planet. Pursued by the Empire’s **sinister** **agents**, Princess Leia races home aboard her starship, custodian of the stolen plans that can save her people and restore freedom to the galaxy...*

And the non-Hopeful words are nowhere in sight. ;)